# Pandas slice multiindex using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Is there a better way of selecting multiple values from a multiindex
instead of

```
df.loc[(slice(None), ['one','seven'], slice(None), ['a','d','l'])]
```

something like:

```
df.loc[ {level_1: ['one','two'], level_3: ['a','d','l'] } ]
```

I tried `df.xs` but this only allows one key per level.

Comment: Can you create a fully working sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]], 
                                   names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': range(12)}, index=index)
```

---

#### [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html)

It's not any different from your original selection, but has slightly more compact syntax because you can use `:` instead of `slice(None)`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['A', :, [1,3]]]

#             data
#foo bar baz      
#A   a   1       0
#        3       2
#    b   1       3
#        3       5
```

---

#### Custom function with np.logical_and.reduce

The function itself is rather verbose but after it's written you can mostly ignore it and deal with the self-documenting signature.

You provide a dict where the keys are the level names (or integer that corresponds to that level number) and the values are the labels you want to include for that level. I added a check that way you can specify an iterable like a list/array/tuple for multiple labels and a single value for levels where you only want need a single label.

```
import numpy as np

def get_slice(df, slice_dict):
    m = np.logical_and.reduce(
            [df.index.get_level_values(level).isin(v) if (hasattr(v, '__iter__') and not isinstance(v, str)) 
             else df.index.get_level_values(level) == v 
             for level,v in slice_dict.items()])
    
    return df.loc[m]


get_slice(df, {'foo': 'A', 'baz': [1, 3]})

#             data
#foo bar baz      
#A   a   1       0
#        3       2
#    b   1       3
#        3       5
```